# count same selected values in datagridview and show count result in QTY column-C#

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I have two datagridview.

1)datagridviewMenu

and

2)Dategrideviewfactor

whenever i choose a row in menu, the row will show in `dategridviewFactor`..

i want the result that i shown in photos, i don't want to add a new row with qty=1 !i want to sum selecting row

1 click Menu row--> QTY=1

2 Click Menu row-->QTY=2

3 Click Menu row-->QTY=3

.
.
.

10 Click Menu row-->QTY=10

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jbxfz.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FuCFN.png)

private void dataGridViewMenu_CellContentClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.ColumnIndex==0)
            {

                SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter(@"select FoodName,FoodCategory,FoodPrice from ResturanFood
                                                        where FoodName='" + dataGridViewMenu.CurrentRow.Cells[0].Value.ToString() + "'", con);
                DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                sda.Fill(dt);
                foreach (DataRow item in dt.Rows)
                {
                    int n = dataGridViewFaktor.Rows.Add();
                    int jam = 1;
                    dataGridViewFaktor.Rows[n].Cells[0].Value = item[0].ToString();
                    dataGridViewFaktor.Rows[n].Cells[1].Value = item[1].ToString();
                    dataGridViewFaktor.Rows[n].Cells[2].Value = item[2].ToString();



                    dataGridViewFaktor.Rows[n].Cells[3].Value = jam;

                    foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridViewFaktor.Rows)
                    {
                        row.Cells[dataGridViewFaktor.Columns["Column6"].Index].Value = (Convert.ToDouble(row.Cells[dataGridViewFaktor.Columns["Column5"].Index].Value) * Convert.ToDouble(row.Cells[dataGridViewFaktor.Columns["Column4"].Index].Value));
                    }
                }
            }
            SumColumn6();
        }

Comment: Is there a question in there somewhere?

Comment: You need to share the _event handler_ code of the _row click event_ so we can understand what you need to fix.

Comment: @KernelMode tanks for your comment, the codes added.

Answer (score 0):

```
            foreach (DataRow item in dt.Rows)
            {
                int n = dataGridViewFaktor.Rows.Add();
```

In the `foreach` above you are adding to `dataGridViewFaktor` a new line in any case **instead of checking before if this row already exists**. If the row already exists, then just update its quantity column value. This way you will get your expected results.

To check if the row already exists, you can compare the `FoodName` columns or preferably the `Food ID`s if you hold it per row.